# Why find is not finding some folders with spaces?

Tags: find, rename

```
find -name "* *" -type d | rename 's/ /_/g'
```

For instance, 'Paired End' folder name on this path is not being replaced with spaces:

```
/home/bernardo/Raw_data/Raw_data_M6_and_V2_UIC_April_2014/Saul_Burdman/Paired End/Burdman_M6_CGTACTAG-CTAAGCCT_L001_R1_001-paired end.fastq.gz
```

Comment: Does `rename` work with directories?

Answer (score 0):

`rename` doesn't support regex on my distro. I have to use `perl-rename`. I am assuming that you're running the above command from a directory above the one in question.